# Indy FTP suddenly disconnect

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

The client always stops downloading at the same point. It downloads exactly 230 of 1310 files each time.

I get following message:

> Connection Closed Gracefully.

The exception is:

> First chance exception at $755FC762. Exception class EIdSocketError
>   with message 'Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.'. Process
>   FTPSTest.exe (8816)

This is my code:

```
var
  ftp: TIdFTP;
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  log: TIdLogFile;
  filename: string;
begin
  ftp := TIdFTP.Create(self);
  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(ftp);
  log := TIdLogFile.Create(ftp);
  try
    log.Filename := Format('C:\ftplog\logfile_%s.log', [FormatDateTime('yyyymmdd_hhnnsszzz', now)]);
    log.Active := true;

    ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    {ssl.SSLOptions.CipherList :=
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:' +
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:' +
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:' +
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:' +
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:' +
      'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:' +
      'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:' +
      'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:' +
      'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:' +
      'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:' +
      'DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:' +
      'DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM';}

    ftp.Intercept := log;
    ftp.IOHandler := ssl;

    ftp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
    ftp.AUTHCmd := tAuthTLS;
    ftp.Host := 'secretdomain.de';
    ftp.Port := 21;
    ftp.Username := 'mysecretuser';
    ftp.Password := 'mysecretpw';
    ftp.Passive := true;
    ftp.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
    ftp.TransferType := ftBinary;
    ftp.ConnectTimeout := 120000;

    ftp.Connect;
      if ftp.Connected then begin
        ftp.ChangeDir('V2_DOWN');
        ftp.List('*.XML', false);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(ftp.ListResult.Count));
        for filename in ftp.ListResult do
          ftp.Get(filename, 'C:\temp\'+filename);
      end;
  finally
    ftp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can have a look at the IdLogFile here: https://pastebin.com/LmcZkrHQ

This is what wireshark has to tell me/us:
[image: wireshark]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 20190722 22:15 CEST**

Yes, the FTP session passing through a router/firewall.
The biggest file is 341.277 Bytes.
It works with other clients like FileZilla.

If I set

```
ftp.NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive := true;
```

then I get

> First chance exception at $755FC762. Exception class EIdSocketError
>   with message 'Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.'. Process
>   FTPSTest.exe (5128)

and next this one

> First chance exception at $755FC762. Exception class EIdNotASocket
>   with message 'Socket Error # 10038 Socket operation on non-socket.'.
>   Process FTPSTest.exe (5128)

**Update 20190722 22:28 CEST**

I've also tried:

```
for i := 0 to ftp.ListResult.Count - 1 do begin
  if i mod 7 = 0 then
    ftp.Noop;
  ftp.Get(ftp.ListResult[i], 'C:\temp\'+ftp.ListResult[i]);
end;
```

**Update 20190723 05:37 CEST**

No changes with

```
ftp.NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS := 12000;
ftp.NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS := 2000;
```

It's a SSL + server firewall issue.

If I comment out these lines, it works perfectly fine. I get all the 1.310 files:

```
ftp.IOHandler := ssl;
ftp.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
ftp.AUTHCmd := tAuthTLS;
ftp.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
```

I disabled all my client firewalls.
Now I am going to ask the server provider for a firewall log on their side.

Comment: If it's an Indy problem, there are experts here who should be able to help you out.  I notice your client is VMWare-hosted and seem to recall encountering a very similar problem bulk-transferring files a few years ago which I overcame by adjusting my VM's connection parameters in an .Ini file somewhere.  I can't remember the details but I didn't have to spend too long googling around to find the solution.

Comment: Is your FTP session passing through a router/firewall? Is file 230/231 a large file? FTP uses separate TCP connections for commands and transfers. While a transfer is in progress, the command connection is sitting idle. An FTP-unaware firewall/router may kill that connection if it is idle for too long. `TIdFTP` has a `NATKeepAlive` property that is disabled by default, try enabling it and see if that helps. It turns on TCP keepalives on the command connection during each transfer so it does not sit idle.

Comment: I have updated my question with more information and answers to your questions. And now I'm really scared because I read the READ ME in the IdStack unit after hitting break on the exception dialog. Will I now be publicly flogged, tarred and feathered?

Comment: @complete_stranger it is not enough to just set `ftp.NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive` to true, you also have to set `ftp.NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS` and `ftp.NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS` to non-zero values, too. Sending `NOOP` in between transfers is not going to help anything, the `NOOP` would have to sent *during* the transfers, which is something `TIdFTP` does not currently support, but `NATKeepAlive` accomplishes the same thing. Not all servers support commands other than `ABOR` during a transfer.

Comment: And it's inconveniences and details like this which is why I abandoned FTP many years ago. It's one of the internet's oldest protocols, even before HTTP. And it's still rather outdated. In fact, if you're working on some sort of software you plan to distribute, be advised that antiviruses love to catch Delphi/Indy FTP code and kill the process assuming it's malware. Antiviruses these days don't like FTP. Neither do firewalls. It was designed before security became a big issue.

Comment: Long story short, only use FTP if you absolutely have to. If you have control over the server-side, choose something else, such as HTTP/REST.  I don't know your implementation intents, but avoid FTP if at all possible. Especially if you plan to distribute this as a consumer product. Because you just don't know what kind of firewalls and/or limitations they have in place. It would become a support nightmare.